# How can I change how an objects field is PRESENTED while still retaining the original value of said field?

Tags: java, json, spring-boot, spring-mvc, jdbctemplate

I'm working on a project that involves creating a Spring Boot REST Application using JDBC Template to access a database of my own creation (MySQL). I'm using Postman to verify endpoints and entering data using JSON through postman. I'm currently tasked with creating a guessing game that generates a random 4 digit number, easy enough. My issue is this; " Returns a specific game based on ID. Be sure in-progress games do not display their answer" I've created a "starter" method that fulfills the requirement, but only at it's most basic level. I cannot operate on an object once it's field's value is changed to "Hidden" as it is no longer a 4 digit number. I'd like to **hide** the answer while still being able to operate in a functional manner on the randomly generate number. Here is my base method for this return:

```
  @Override
public Game gameById(int id) {
    Game game = gameDao.getGameById(id);
    if (game.getFinished() == false) { // "Hides" the answer
        game.setGameAnswer("Hidden");
    }     
    return game;
}
```

Here is my method that uses the above code in my application:

```
@PostMapping("/guess") 
public ResponseEntity<Game> play( int id, String guess) {
        Game game = service.gameById(id); // Get method
        if (game == null) {
   return new ResponseEntity(null, HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
     }
        Round round = new Round();
        round.setGuess(guess);
        service.guess(round, game);
        return ResponseEntity.ok(game);
    }
```

Any ideas?

EDIT:

Game Object:

```
public class Game {
int gameId;
String gameAnswer;
Boolean finished;
List<Round> Rounds = new ArrayList<>();
```

I will also include the database game table which i am storing said fields into:

```
   CREATE TABLE game(
id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
gameAnswer CHAR(4) NOT NULL,
finished BOOLEAN DEFAULT false
);
```

To clarify my question, when running the game in postman, the game object and it's fields are all displayed as well as the games answer. My goal is to **hide** this answer as long as the games status reads "false". Once the number has been correctly guessed the status of the game will automatically be set to true.

Here is an example from the JSON output of postman:

```
{
"gameId": 1,
"gameAnswer": "2651",
"finished": false,
"rounds": [
    {
        "roundId": 1,
        "guess": "1234",
        "timeOfGuess": "2021-06-18 09:28:29",
        "exactMatch": 0,
        "partialMatch": 0,
        "gameId": 1
    }
]
```

}

While the "Finished" is set to false, I want the game answer to read "Hidden", but still have the numerical value be present to operate on.

Guess Method:

```
    @Override
public void guess(Round round, Game game) {
    // Takes the games generated answer and the user's guess and breaks them down into character array's
    round.setGameId(game.getGameId());
    char[] gameAnswer = characterBreakDown(game.getGameAnswer());
    char[] roundGuess = characterBreakDown(round.getGuess());

    // used for comparing the array elements one by one
    int min = 0;
    int max = 1;
    int exact = 0;
    boolean run = true;
    while (run) {
        for (int i = 0; i <= 3; i++) {
            if (Arrays.equals(roundGuess, gameAnswer)) {
                round.setExactMatch(4);
                game.setFinished(true);
                gameDao.updateGameById(game);
                run = false;
            } else if (Arrays.equals(roundGuess, min, max, gameAnswer, min, max)) {
                exact++;
                round.setExactMatch(exact);
                min++;
                max++;
                if (i == 3 && round.getExactMatch() >= 2) {
                    round.setPartialMatch(round.getExactMatch());
                    run = false;
                } else if (i == 3) {
                    run = false;
                }
            } else if (!Arrays.equals(roundGuess, min, max, gameAnswer, min, max)) {
                min++;
                max++;
                if (i == 3 && round.getExactMatch() >= 2) {
                    round.setPartialMatch(round.getExactMatch());
                    run = false;
                } else if (i == 3) {
                    run = false;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    game.getRounds().add(round);
    roundDao.createRound(round);
}
```

Comment: Could you show us a snippet of the Game object?

Comment: And let me clarify, you have a 4-digit guessing game that is stored using JDBC & MySQL. Looking at the fact that you have `game.getFinished()`, this means you can have multiple 'game sessions' running per se. Your goal is to retrieve any game using its database ID or any intrinsically linked one, but when the game is unfinished, you want the player to continue? (Another way of saying `don't display answer`)

Comment: I'd recommend rephrasing your question and adding some supporting code snippets and examples. I understand the idea but it seems a little unclear to me what you're trying to achieve. E.g. Display some examples of what functionality you want, be it visual or code-based, it helps others understand your problem more.

Comment: Thank for reply, Alex. I'm still working on the "Ask good questions" part. My goal in this endeavor is to hide the output of the game object's "answer" field as long as the finished boolean is set as false. @Alex I've added some more clarification, if it isn't an inconvenience please let me know if there's anything more I should clarify. Thank you again! Also to answer your second question; once a game is finished the only thing that is changed is that the finished boolean is set to true and if the game is retrieved from the DB the answer is present instead of being hidden.

Comment: I'm don't understand your statement, "I'd like to hide the answer while still being able to operate in a functional manner on the randomly generate number".

If you want to hide the answer from the client of your api, then you are already doing the correct thing (though I'd probably set the 'gameAnswer' to either null or an empty string).

What do you mean by "still being able to operate in a functional manner on the randomly generate number"? You're not changing it in the database, are you?

Comment: At first sight, your code seems okay. Have you debugged it to the point `return ResponseEntity.ok(game);` ? What is the value of gameAnswer there? Is this value changed in the guess method?

Comment: Thanks for the replies @rawdog. While i am fulfilling the requirement of hiding a game's answer that is unfinished, I am also using that same get method to retrieve an object from my DB and operate on it with my guess method I've added above. My issue is that once I've pulled that game from the DB using that method, I've replaced the 4 digit number and replaced with with a "Hidden" string. Which is my issue. When using postman to run my play method if i were to use a generic GET method as my object retrieval it would show the answer as you can see from the above JSON output

Comment: @GreyBeardedGeek thank you for the reply and helping me clarify my question to help an outsider audience understand my request.  I am not changing the object in the DB until a correct answer is made which would then run an UPDATE query and set the "finished" boolean to "True", thus revealing the answer as the game is no longer in progress. I'm using that same get method that hides the object as a means to retrieve said object from my DB to use my "Guess" method on, but once retrieved the answer is set to "Hidden" and Is used to compare against a user's inputted guess.

Comment: @GreyBeardedGeek I want to omit the answer from showing in JSON, but I've i grab an object it's value will be shown regardless. I've asked my instructors and they've said the challenge of the project is to "hide the value ONLY when it is being presented to the user". Essentially what the user see's would by my "Hidden" String instead of the randomly generated answer while that answer is still present behind the veil of secrecy. I'm unsure of how to achieve this feat. Displaying the game object while hiding the answer yet still using the answer as a reference when guessing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, your issue is that in one use case (when you are responding to an API request), you want to retrieve a Game and respond to the API request with the Game's "gameAnswer" field hidden, but for other, purely background operations, you want to retrieve the Game with the "gameAnswer" field intact.

Assuming that's the case, I think that your only real issue is where you "blank-out" the "gameAnswer" field.

It looks like you are currently doing that in the "gameById" method of the repository. That results in the gameAnswer being hidden in all cases, right?

So, the solution would be to blank-out the gameAnswer in the controller method instead.

If I have this wrong / backwards I apologize, but the way that you posted your code, in pieces, makes it hard to follow. But anyway, I believe that the solution to your problem is to only blank-out the field where it actually needs to be blanked out. Or if you are having some other issue with it being blanked out / not blanked out because you are doing so in some shared method, perhaps create a new method for the use-case that needs it the other way.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help @GreyBeardedGeek and to everyone else who commented despite the formatting of the question and puzzle like snippets of code, lol. The moment you mentioned blanking the answer out in the controller method, I realized i would change my Get method to a generic retrieval method without modifying the contents and then run the object through my controller method and set the conditional at the end, and it worked exactly how I wanted it to! In the future I will remember the advice given for posting questions Thanks again!